# Resolve docker.errors.TLSParameterError

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to bring up an application that needs to reach out to Dind (Docker in Docker):

```
meta_docker:
    image: docker:stable-dind
    privileged: true
    networks:
      meta_docker_net:
        aliases:
          - docker
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - /srv/databases:/srv/databases
      - meta_docker_data:/var/lib/docker
      - meta_docker_certs_ca:/certs/ca
      - meta_docker_certs_client:/certs/client
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    command: "--dns 8.8.8.8"
    restart: unless-stopped

  meta_system:
    image: quay.io/jhuapl/meta_system
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    init: true
    depends_on:
      - meta_docker
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5000:5000"
    networks:
      - default
      - meta_docker_net
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - /srv/databases:/srv/databases
      - meta_docker_certs_client:/certs/client:ro
    environment:
      META_DEBUG: "false"
      META_SERVER_BIND: "0.0.0.0"
      META_SERVER_PORT: 5000
      META_DATA_DIR: "/data"
      META_MONGO_HOST: "mongodb"
      META_MONGO_PORT: 27017
      META_BIOCONTAINER_DB_DIR: "/srv/databases"
      UID_REMAP: ${UID_REMAP:-999}
      GID_REMAP: ${GID_REMAP:-999}
      DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2376"
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "/certs/client"
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: "1"
    command: ["python3", "run_app.py"]
    restart: unless-stopped
```

When I bring it up through `docker-compose up`, I see the following error:

```
docker.errors.TLSParameterError: Path to a certificate and key files must be provided through the client_cert param. LS configurations should map the Docker CLI client configurations. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/ for API details.
```

and the app cannot connect to the Dind:

```
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985104445Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985109193Z   File "run_app.py", line 28, in <module>
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985114328Z     load_biocontainers()
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985119109Z   File "/home/meta/biocontainers_utils.py", line 112, in load_biocontainers
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985124114Z     img = client.images.load(docker_tar)[0]
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985128893Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 382, in load
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985133984Z     resp = self.client.api.load_image(data)
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985139086Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 312, in load_image
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985144206Z     res = self._post(
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985149076Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985154157Z     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985159044Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 224, in _post
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985164037Z     return self.post(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985168871Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985173865Z     return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985178840Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985183860Z     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985193193Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985198518Z     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985203360Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985208269Z     raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
2023-07-04T21:55:52.985213090Z requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2376): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

If I look at the logs of the Dind:

```
2023-07-04T21:49:52.715087098Z time="2023-07-07T01:19:17.714936319Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
2023-07-04T21:49:52.757200545Z time="2023-07-07T01:19:17.757028110Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
2023-07-04T21:49:52.780216359Z time="2023-07-07T01:19:17.779980452Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=5eb3275 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.14
2023-07-04T21:49:52.780301983Z time="2023-07-07T01:19:17.780183601Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
2023-07-04T21:49:52.814383747Z time="2023-07-07T01:19:17.814186053Z" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2376"
2023-07-04T21:49:52.814623069Z time="2023-07-07T01:19:17.814274112Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

So, the Docker in Docker (Dind) process is listening on 2376.

I have specified DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR and DOCKER_CERT_PATH.

Thoughts on what I am missing in the configuration that is causing this issue?